# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when creating text based game

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting, pycharm, typeerror

I am working on a project for school where I have to make a game where the character travels through rooms to collect items. I keep getting this error

```
player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```py
rooms = {
        'Laundry Room': {'West': 'Basement'}, #Game Starts Here
        'Basement': {'North': 'Kitchen'},
        'Kitchen': {'West': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Basement'},
        'Living Room': {'East': 'Kitchen', 'item': '$100 cash'},
        'Dining Room': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Backyard', 'item': '$6 cash'},
        'Bedroom': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Bathroom', 'item': '$200 cash'},
        'Bathroom': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'item': '$300 cash'},
        'Backyard': {'South': 'Dining Room', 'item': '$60 cash'} #Return to the Laundry Room via the Basement
}

player_move = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
currentRoom = rooms['Laundry Room']

# While Loop for moving between rooms
while True:


    player_move = input('Enter a move: \n')

    if player_move == 'Exit':
        print('Thanks for playing.')
        # break statement for exiting
        break

    if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]

        addItem = input(' \n')

        if 'item' in rooms[currentRoom]:
            game(rooms[currentRoom]['item'])
```

I tried a few solutions but none of them worked, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the code where `player_move` and `currrentRoom` are initially defined. It appears that one of those is a dictionary and you can't have a dictionary as a key of a dictionary since its a mutable type.

Comment: @NotAName You can see how `player_move` is defined, it's a string from `input()`. So the problem must be that `current_room` is a room dictionary rather than a room name.

Comment: @Barmar, oh yes. Missed that.

Comment: I updated my post above and included the dictionary of rooms please tell me how I can fix this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
currentRoom = rooms['Laundry Room']
```

here the value of `currentRoom` is a dictionary `{'West': 'Basement'}`.

```
if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
```

so here you are testing if `player_move` in `rooms[{'West': 'Basement'}]` which is not valid.

so use either:

```py
currentRoom = 'Laundry Room'
...
if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]
# --OR--
currentRoom = rooms['Laundry Room']
...
if player_move in currentRoom:
    currentRoom = currentRoom[player_move]
```

using some `print` statements goes a long way in debugging.

Comment: I replace the code with currentRoom = 'Laundry Room'
...
if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]

Comment: and testing here, you can move from room to room. [https://onlinegdb.com/G7t8CZ3eB](https://onlinegdb.com/G7t8CZ3eB)